# Microsoft Excel - Creating Two Columns From One

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have one column of 3000 rows with data like so:

```
domain, name
```

So something like: `harvard.edu, Harvard University`

Some of the names do have punctuation in them and all of the domains end with .edu

I want to split that up so that I have two columns: name and domain

Answer (score 1):

Select the entire column then Data -> Text to columns
Choose comma as the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Using Data> Text to Columns specifying delimited by comma will give you "Harvard.edu" in the original column and " Harvard University" in the next column to the right.

Alternatively, you could use formulae:

If your data is in column A, enter

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(", ",A1)-1)
```

in B1 and then in C1

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1))
```

This should work because the domain will not contain spaces.  The `-1` gets rid of the comma after domain.